# Why am I getting "Invalid token _ in class.." and "The name _ does not exist in the current context? C#

Tags: c#

Newbie here, please be forgiving. I'm trying to make use of this API https://coinmarketcap.com/api/

It shows the object setup as follows:

```
 [
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "573.137", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "72855700.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "9080883500.0", 
        "available_supply": "15844176.0", 
        "total_supply": "15844176.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.04", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-0.3", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-0.57", 
        "last_updated": "1472762067"
    }
]
```

In my project I have a class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CoinData
{
    public class CoinData
    {
        public decimal rank { get; set; }
        public decimal price_usd { get; set; }
        public decimal price_btc { get; set; }
        public decimal 24h_volume_usd { get; set; }
        public decimal market_cap_usd { get; set; }
    }
}
```

It complains about having the '24' as the start of the object property name. But if that's how the API returns it, how can I get round it?

"Invalid token '24' in class, struct, or interface member declaration."
"h_volume_usd does not exist in the current context."

Comment: variable names cannot start with numbers

Answer (score 6):

C# identifiers cannot start with a number.

Depending on your JSON serializer, you should be able to set an attribute to map a C# property name to a different JSON property name.